# Dynamic number of side-by-side plots in Shiny with bootstrap

Tags: r, shiny

I used [this example](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415) to generate a dynamic number of plots in my Shiny app.

The issue is that I need the plots to responsively fill side-by-side rather than below each other: i.e dynamically using the available Bootstrap columns.

I tried following the [comment](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415#gistcomment-1646351) further down the page that claims to do this but I can't get it working properly and don't follow the code (e.g., placement of `plotOutput` and `renderPlot` seems strange).

I managed to get the responsive grid working correctly using this latter method but the figures don't appear on the page (they appear in the image window in the RStudio console).

I've searched but can't find any more info on responsive grid for dynamic number of plots. I need to use base graphics and prefer not to use `layout` to set up the entire plot space as I already am using `layout` to plot multiple plots within each main plot.

Here is the code from the first link to plot dynamic number of figures. I would like the plots to fill side-by-side with responsive number of rows.

```
max_plots <- 12

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
        headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
            uiOutput("plots")
        )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
    output$plots <- renderUI({
        plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
            plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
            plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
        })
        # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
        # to display properly.
        do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
    })
    # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
    # are visible on the web page.
    for (i in 1:max_plots) {
        # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
        # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
        # of when the expression is evaluated.
        local({
            my_i <- i
            plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

            output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
                plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
                     xlim = c(1, max_plots),
                     ylim = c(1, max_plots),
                     main = paste("1:", my_i, ".  n is ", input$n, sep = "")
                )
            })
        })
    }
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Appreciate any tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flowLayout` instead of `tagList`.

[image]